# Get Chip Text on click chip

Tags: java, android, android-chips

I am new to android and trying to play with chips. I have chip group like this in xml

```
<com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup
                                android:padding="10dp"
                                android:id="@+id/tags"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                app:chipSpacing="10dp">

                            </com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup>
```

I am dynamically adding chip like this in it.

```
Chip chip = new Chip(getLayoutInflater().getContext());
            for(String genre : tags_text) {
               chip.setText(genre);
               tags.addView(chip);
           }
```

Adding chip is working fine. Now I want get chip text of clicked chip. I am trying to get it like this

```
chip.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                                        public void onClick(View v) {
                                            int chipsCount = tags.getChildCount();
                                            String TagText ="";
                                            int i = 0;
                                            while (i < chipsCount) {
                                                Chip chip = (Chip) tags.getChildAt(i);
                                                if (chip.isChecked() ) {
                                                    TagText = chip.getText().toString();
                                                }
                                                i++;
                                            };
                                            Log.e("CHIPS", TagText+"-OK");
                                        }
                                    });
```

But I am getting empty text always. let me know if someone can help me for solve it.
Thanks!

Comment: Inside your listener, in onClick method you get View v parameter. Which is exactly the clicked chip. So inside onClick you can do just "TagText = ((Chip) v).getText().toString()" and then Log it. No need for cycles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
    chip.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String text = ((Chip) view).getText().toString();
            //...
        }
    });
```